# Source code hosting for ASP.NET and WCF projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

I'm working on a project with 2 other developers and I need to host it online. I need a site to host it for me with features such as version control, and others neat features.

can you suggest any ?

the project is not an open source one.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [XP-Dev](http://www.xp-dev.com), would work well for you, they offer a free plan that has two private projcets. [Pricing is here.](http://www.xp-dev.com/pricing)

Answer (score 1):

I use projectlocker.com
They have a free version.
One of the nice features is the monthly report that shows you what everyone on your team did.

Answer (score 0):

BitBucket, with Mercurial-based source control, has private repositories:

http://bitbucket.org/plans/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) and highly recommend it. It's free for 200MB/2 users. Subversion and Git are supported and the interface is nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of webhosts include these features as part of the normal monthly hosting plans. For example I use dreamhost.com and get subversion and trac included.